# redaction_tool (johnff/redaction_tool) throws error in API explorer

Tags: api

I want to try out [redaction_tool](https://github.com/JohnFF/redaction_tool) in the CiviCRM Api explorer v3, so I can later use the redact API call in a script. So I called the `redact` method on `Contact` with a certain Contact ID.
But the API explorer returns:

```
{
 "is_error": 1,
 "error_message": "'Guest Referral' is not a valid option for field activity_type_id"
}
```

How can I find out what is going wrong?
It doesn't seem clear to me why the `redact` call is even trying to write in `activity_type_id` column in the database.
I couldn't find any helpful resources online.

Also, when I run the API `get` call on the same `Contact`, the returned array contains nothing like an `activity_type_id`.